# How do I create a simple connection with Node.js to a DynamoDB table?

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I'm doing:

```
  AWS.config.update({ accessKeyId: process.env['AWS_ACCESS_KEY'], secretAccessKey: process.env['AWS_SECRET_KEY'] })
  const dynamoClient = new DynamoDB.DocumentClient()
  console.log(dynamoClient)
```

but it gives:

```
...
    endpoint: Endpoint {
      protocol: 'https:',
      host: 'dynamodb.undefined.amazonaws.com',
      port: 443,
      hostname: 'dynamodb.undefined.amazonaws.com',
      pathname: '/',
      path: '/',
      href: 'https://dynamodb.undefined.amazonaws.com/'
    }
...
```

Where do I get (and specify) my `endpoint`?

Comment: Did you try to add the region as well?

Comment: where would I specify that?

Comment: on the aws sdk initialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go [here for a bunch of great Node.js examples](https://github.com/synchrophoto/DynamoDB-SDK-examples/tree/master/node.js) of working with DynamoDB. If what you are looking for is not there, please let me know.

Comment: Do I need to define a schema ahead of time? I get `The provided key element does not match the schema`

Comment: You need to at least define the primary key when you create a DynamoDB table. That primary key can be either just a partition key or it can be a combination of the partition and sort keys. It all depends on the access patterns you plan to support with the table.

Comment: Follow up if you have a minute: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62285490/how-to-define-a-return-type-for-a-dynamodb-get-with-typescript