# How to define a return type for a DynamoDB get with TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-dynamodb

I have:

```
  let resItem: Schema

  resItem = await dynamoClient.get({
    TableName,
    Key: {
      uuid: request.body.uuid
    }
  }).promise()
```

but I get:

```
Type 'PromiseResult<GetItemOutput, AWSError>' is missing the following properties from type 'Schema': uuid, topics, phoneNumber, timezonets(2739)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check [the definition of GetItemOutput](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/e4d1a07e0d51e78fb268bcbebe23736416e4346a/clients/dynamodb.d.ts#L1326) and [the definition of PromiseResult](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/41c9d5a2ca0c455bea55c98bb99e647eed2c8781/lib/request.d.ts#L329) you will see that the promise is returning an object of `{Item, ConsumedCapacity, $response}` but not the result only. So I think you should use `PromiseResult` as the type and use the `Item` attribute as your result.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. This is known as the lazy way. As there is no way of knowing if the properties in the type `ReturnType` are actually there at runtime.

But the content is coming from a database call and we expect dynamoDB to work, that's why we don't unit test it.

```
export const get = async <ReturnType>(params: DynamoDB.DocumentClient.GetItemInput) => {
  try {
    const result = await dynamodb.get(params).promise();
    return {...result, Item: result.Item as ReturnType};
  } catch (error) {
    throw Error(error);
  }
};
```